# Java versions to use for Gradle 'sourceCompatibility' and 'targetCompatibility'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I can't find any information on what Java versions
can be used for the choices for Android Gradle 'sourceCompatibility'
and 'targetCompatibility'.

I can get the current Java JDK path like: 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45'
to '1.7', so would the choices be '1.7' and '1.6'?

Or if you had a path to '1.8':  '1.8', '1.7' and '1.6'?

How do I figure out what choices are available?

Thanks!

Comment: This works for my build.gradle file: `java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17`

Answer (score 0):

As for me - i am using Android Studio with Gradle - only vialble options are 1_6 and 1_7 - depending on what Java language level you want to use. I tried 1_8 (lambdas and predicates look cool) but it requires also enabling Jack compiler - which is hell in Android Studio i couldn't beat.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Gradle is using the current jdk/JVM as the upper limit
of the Java version.

Thanks